# C#: PictureBox override Width

Tags: c#, overriding, picturebox

How can i override the Width property of a PictureBox? (i need to set the base.Width, but additional to execute a method)

Following isn't working:

```
public class l33tProgressBar : PictureBox
{
    public override int Width
    {
        get { return this.Width; }
        set
        {
            myMethod();

            base.Width = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Width` is not virtual, so you cant override it. You can however, overwrite it using the `new` keyword.

```
public new int Width
{
    get { return base.Width; }
    set
    {
        myMethod();

        base.Width = value;
    }
}
```

However, a better option *might* be to override the `SizeChanged` <sup>([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onsizechanged.aspx))</sup> event handler instead

```
public override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
   // Width or Height has been changed
   base.OnSizeChanged(e); // Essential, or event will not be raised!
}
```

Comment: thx a lot, this works great: 'code' protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
   // Width or Height has been changed
   base.OnSizeChanged(e); // Essential, or event will not be raised!
}

Answer (score 1):

Creating a method for it would probably be cleaner. Hiding a method call in what others would expect to be an inherited property isn't a readable or maintainable approach.

```
public class l33tProgressBar : PictureBox
{
    public void SetWidthMyWay(int width)
    {
        myMethod();
        this.Width = width;
    }
}
```